# Sort an array of objects within an array by most recent timestamp, and then sort the outer array by each array's first object's timestamp, using jq

Tags: json, jq

Sort an array of objects within an array by most recent timestamp, and then sort the outer array by each array's first object's timestamp, using `jq`.

This is an example of the JSON data, at the stage of the `jq` pipeline where I'm stuck.

```
[
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:46.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867515456237571",
      "id": "1309867515456237571",
      "text": "example1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:47.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867518455156736",
      "id": "1309867518455156736",
      "text": "example2"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:47.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867518455156736",
      "id": "1309867517846810625",
      "text": "example3"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:46.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867518455156736",
      "id": "1309867516659937284",
      "text": "example4"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:48.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867524473999364",
      "id": "1309867524473999364",
      "text": "example5"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:47.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867524473999364",
      "id": "1309867520468291586",
      "text": "example6"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:47.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867524473999364",
      "id": "1309867520153845760",
      "text": "example7"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2020-09-26T14:48:48.000Z",
      "conversation_id": "1309867524750749705",
      "id": "1309867524750749705",
      "text": "example8"
    }
  ]
]
```

Everything I've tried ends up with an error like this one,

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:8): Cannot index string with string "created_at"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
jq '.[] |= sort_by(.created_at) | sort_by(.[].created_at)'
```